# Is there a way to bind a property to the value it would have had if it wasn't bound

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a TextBlock which I'd like to display at double the ambient font size.

For example, if I just had:

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello world" />
```

it would display at (for example) font size 14, but I'd like it to display at size 28. The "obvious" approach of binding to itself (below) causes a `StackOverflowException`, as you might expect:

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello world" 
    FontSize="{Binding FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource ValueDoublingConverter}}" />
```

This leaves me with using something like `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UIElement}` or `ElementName=SomeAncestorControl`, both of which seem a bit daft (having to go off and look for another control when the `TextBlock` has access to the `FontSize` itself).

So my question is: is there a way to double the `FontSize` of a `TextBlock` without having to involve another control in the binding process?

Comment: Set its LayoutTransform to an appropriate ScaleTransform.

Comment: That's something I did forget to mention - a LayoutTransform also seems a bit heavy duty for something as simple as text size (possibly moreso than the ElementName approach?)

Comment: @PhilipC have u checked my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since WPF uses vector graphics, there is no difference in doubling the font size of a TextBlock or just scaling the entire element by a factor of 2.

So you may just set an appropriate `LayoutTransform`:

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello, World">
    <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
    </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
</TextBlock>
```

Or shorter, by using an implicit type conversion from `string` to `MatrixTransform`:

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello, World" LayoutTransform="2,0,0,2,0,0"/>
```

Comment: It does surprise me that a LayoutTransform is no more costly than setting the font size, but if that is the case, then this must be the sensible approach. Also, I haven't seen that string conversion for a matrix transform in XAML before - that's quite a space saver.

Comment: What exactly does "costly" mean? Especially when there is no other "sensible" approach. Keep in mind that it's paradox to set a property to "twice its value". Then what is its actual value, the original or the result value? How should it behave if the original value is later changed, e.g. by a style change?

Comment: I don't have any specific meaning for "costly", just a vague sense of the "amount of work" the computer has to do (for example, if the text updates frequently, minimising the work would be helpful). I had assumed that using a larger font size vs scaling the resulting string were two different operations, and that the former might be cheaper than the latter. If, as you say, they're the same operation, then that's fine and I'm happy with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches :

1. Creating a new control inheriting `TextBlock`.

   ```
   public class MyTextBlock : TextBlock
   {
       static MyTextBlock()
       {
           TextBlock.FontSizeProperty.OverrideMetadata(
               typeof(MyTextBlock),
               new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                   TextElement.FontSizeProperty.DefaultMetadata.DefaultValue,
                   TextElement.FontSizeProperty.DefaultMetadata.PropertyChangedCallback,
                   new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceFontSizeProperty))
           );
       }

       private static object CoerceFontSizeProperty(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
       {
           // increase fontsize 2 times    
           return (double)baseValue * 2;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Pure XAML using `Inlines` collection, eg; 
   Try changing `FontSize` of `Label` to and other than 24. Our `IValueConverter` does the magical work here.

   ```
   <Label FontSize="24" Margin="58,205,325,10"  Width="147">
     <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top">
       <TextBlock.Inlines>
           <Run x:Name="Run1" Text="Hi" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfStackOverflow">
               <Run.Style>
                   <Style TargetType="Run">
                       <Style.Triggers>
                           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBlock, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="24">
                               <Setter Property="FontSize">
                                       <Setter.Value>
                                           <Binding Path="FontSize" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBlock, Mode=FindAncestor}">
                                               <Binding.Converter>
                                                   <local:DoubleFontSizeConverter/>
                                               </Binding.Converter>
                                           </Binding>
                                       </Setter.Value>
                                   </Setter>
                           </DataTrigger>
                       </Style.Triggers>
                   </Style>
               </Run.Style>
           </Run>
       </TextBlock.Inlines>
     </TextBlock>
   </Label>
   ```

   *Converter*

   ```
   public class DoubleFontSizeConverter : IValueConverter
   {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
          // increase font size 5 times 
          return (double)value*5;
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I don't understand how either of these are going to help: 1. Create a new control which does what? 2. This seems to just change the size of one bit of text to a constant value if another bit of text has its size set to another constant value, which is not what I'm after.

Comment: @PhilipC have u checked the answer